# Getting Port already in use: 6969; nested exception on tomcat while start up?

Tags: tomcat

i have my one  application published on 8080 port and when i access it with url http://localhost:8080/fipWebApp/login.do it works fine. **I published the same application on another port 8888 but when i start this server on this port it gives me below error

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 6969; nested exception is:  
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind 
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:310) 
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:218) **
```

Though at  last of console stack trace it also says  that

```
Dec 9, 2011 11:31:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-80
Dec 9, 2011 11:31:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1793 ms
```

**I am not sure what i am missing here though i have not installed any application on port 8888?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue. Port 6969 was used by other instance of tomcat for some jmx service. Sotpped the instance and got rid of this issue
.