# java.net.BindException: RMI port already in use Error

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application running on Tomcat and after weekly maintenance it has suddenly stopped working. Looking into the logs, I get the following error:

```
2015-06-22 10:10:03,351 [RMIStartThread] ERROR com.corda.ccutil - Found an  existing RMI
registry on 10.0.5.143 with port: 2021
java.net.BindException: RMI port already in use
    at com.corda.ccutil.te.a(te.java:43)
    at com.corda.cvserver.kb.run(kb.java:50)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As indicated in some of other blogs where people had this problem ([Getting Port already in use: 6969; nested exception on tomcat while start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441778/getting-port-already-in-use-6969-nested-exception-on-tomcat-while-start-up)), I looked up what was using port 2021 using `netstat -anob` command. Here is the output:

[image]

Using tasklist to then find the process with PID 2700, i get the output:

[image]

If its tomcat using the port 2021, why is there a problem then? I have tried restarting the server, stopping and starting tomcat and the web application. The application seems to work fine locally, but doesn't open up on any other remote location.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might have gone wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your tomcat had stopped suddenly without liberating the used port and resources. 
You can face this situation for example  if you're running Tomcat in your IDE like eclipse and then close Eclipse without shutting down the server so the resources used by the server will not be liberated.

Just kill the process that use the ports and then restart your server and it will work fine.

Comment: Hi, I killed the process and restarted the server but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Be sure that the process not still runing. Stop your server and execute netstat to see if the port is always in use. if so kill the process and verify after using netstat again.

Comment: I have already checked that. As soon as I close Tomcat, the port is free and nothing else is seen on the port. Also, an internal link to the web application is working. Does it mean that the application is not being deployed on port 2021 because of the RMI port or is the mapping between the internal and the external link has gone wrong?

Comment: Do you think emptying the work directory of Tomcat could help in this case?

Comment: If i am not  mistaken you have another application in your tomcat that use rmi registry. Remove yours and run tomcat then check the ports